# how to hide past dates in input type = "Date"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, bootstrap-4

```
  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

There is dropdown calender but i want restrict it from showing or selecting past dates.
Is there anyway to do it.

Comment: Set the `min` attribute …? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#htmlattrdefmin

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments by @CBroe, the [`min` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#htmlattrdefmin) is what you're looking for.

The javascript code

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

returns the date string in the required format.

See the following snippet:

```js
let input = document.querySelector(".form-control").min = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

```html
  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

Answer (score 1):

try min attribute like this

```
let input = document.querySelector(".form-control").min = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `min` and `max` attribute in date input to restrict future dates and past dates

> If you set **max** attribute to current date then it will only allow you to select the past dates.

> If you set **min** attribute to current date then it will only allow you to select the future dates.

**Syntax:**

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2021-04-21" max="2018-12-31">
```

**Hide Past Dates**

```
<form>
  <label for="party">Choose your preferred party date:
    <input type="date" name="party" min="2021-04-21">
  </label>
</form>
```

Check this link for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = document.querySelector(".form-control").min = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

```html
  <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34125018)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ="date" class="form-cotrol" id="newdate" name"expire_date">
<script>
  $(function(){
    var dtToday = new Date();

    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate();
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day.toString();

    var minDate= year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

    $('#newdate').attr('min', minDate);
});
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).